# SSIS package creation for integrating MSSQL and MySql dbs

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, bids, data-integration

I am trying to create an SSIS package for integrating between MSSQL and MYSQL. I have no prior experience of working with Bids or SSIS and following the instructions from [here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/andy_leonard/archive/2007/07/09/ssis-design-pattern-incremental-loads.aspx).

I added the OLE DB Source, Lookup, Conditional Split, OLE DB Destination and OLE DB Command components to the Data Flow and configured the connection managers and column mappings upto the Conditional Split component.

From here, I am facing two problems -

1) After configuring the OLE DB Destination, it shows error symbol on the component that says `could not convert between unicode and non unicode string datatypes`. To solve this, I tried to insert a Data Conversion Component between the Conditional Split and the Destination and configured it for the problematic column. But that doesnt seem to help

2) While configuring the OLE DB Command, the right hand side column in Column mappings tab shows zero columns. I have added the Sql command with question marks so i guess it should be showing columns named "Param_0", "Param_1" etc if i am not wrong. I even tried to add them manually from the input and output properties tab but then it shows the warning, `external columns for OLE DB command are out of sync with data source`

What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: are you performing a one-off migration? Or incremental loads?

Comment: if you mean migrating only once, then no. A job will be scheduled at a specific time everyday when all new changes to the mssql db during the day will be copied to mysql. Both databases will be on the same server.

Answer (score 1):

The way you describe your first problem, it sounds like it should work.  Here are a couple of things to check.

1. The data conversion component creates a new column for the converted data.  Make sure you are referring to it in your following transformations and destination.
2. Right-click on the Data Conversion component and select Advanced Editor.  Select the Input and Output Properties tab in the Advanced Editor.  Expand the Data Conversion Output branch of the tree-view and select your new column.  Ensure that the Data Type Properties show the data type that you want to convert too.  If these values are not right then something is not right with the setup in the component.

For your second problem, the issue can frequently be caused by an error with the SqlCommand value.  First, make sure the Connection Manager is correct on the Connection Manager tab.  Switch to the Column Mappings tab.  Near the bottom of the form, there may be a warning message that indicates that the SQL statement cannot be prepared.  In other words, SSIS can't figure out what the statement is supposed to do.  Address any problems with the SQL statement and switch back to the Column Mappings tab.  The columns will appear once the SQL statement can be parsed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I cannot try this now for a couple of days. will try and get back with updates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the conversion issues then change your destination table column types from char/varchar to nchar/nvarchar.  I'm pretty sure you will need to use an ADO connector for mysql source and destinations, you should be able to read data from the mysql source and write to the mssql database w/o using anything other than source and destination components.